# Is there any quick way to force Lua to keep the call stack of a tail-call?

Tags: lua

Every now and then, the call stack gets broken where there is a tail-call, which is quite annoying. So I need a way to get the complete call stack. I mean, other than rewriting the program so that the tail-call doesn't exist any more, of course. Maybe a switch somewhere which I can turn on or off?

Comment: You can write a preprocessor to replace `return <ret-values>` with `return (function (...) return ... end)(<ret-values>)` in all your Lua files

Comment: Try [this preprocessor](https://pastebin.com/g3nA9TCC)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Wow, that sounds a good idea! But the code looks a bit complicated and merits some careful study. Thank you!

Comment: This code may work incorrectly with programs containing comments.  Remove the line `:gsub("(%s+)"..end_retval, end_retval.."%1")` to fix this problem.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff OK, that looks perfect. But how shall I use it? Does it apply to only one file at one time?

Comment: Yes, one file at a time.  You should write bash or cmd script to traverse all your lua files in your project folder and invoke preprocessor for every file :-)

Comment: I hope all your files have last line terminated with a newline character (LF or CRLF).  Otherwise, use `program = io.read"*a".."\n"`

Comment: See also http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-09/msg01067.html